# Can I use methods from my own files in an external framework that I added?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I'm using the QuickDialog framework https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog , which adds around 80 files to my project. In one of the files, I'd like to use one of the functions I wrote in my project.

So, I have a method that I call like so:

```
[ActivityImage getActivityImage:2];
```

When I head to the top of the file and add

```
#import "ActivityImage+Functions.h"
```

it tells me the file cannot be found. `ActivityImage+Functions.h` is a Category file. Is there some special way to import my own files into an external frameworks files?

Thanks

#### UPDATE

To be more clear: In one of QuickDialogs files, specifically QLabelElement.m I want to add in one of the method calls I wrote in my project. The QuickDialog framework was added as a submodule to my project, I dragged in the QuickDialog .xcodeproj file, and then added as a Target Dependency for my project.

I can #import files from the QuickDialog framework to my project files, but I can't go the other way.

Comment: I'm confused; how is this adding a file into an external framework?

Comment: Is it a proper framework (with that file-extension) or is it just a bunch of implementation files and headers that you are using within your project (possibly as a subproject)?

Comment: I guess I wrote a poor title. What I meant was the ability to include my own methods in some of a frameworks files. For example, there is a file that I edited in QuickDialog that handles how a tableview works. However, I'd like to include some of my own methods from my project into the framework. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, I edited my question to make it more understandable (I think!).

Comment: Add the category file in to the QuickDialog.xcodeproj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [Objective-C Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Add a header file in your own project called `ActivityImage+MyStuff.h` (note the `+MyStuff` can be something more appropriate):

```
#import "ActivityImage.h"

@interface ActivityImage (MyStuff)

+ (void)getActivityImage:(NSUInteger)someInteger;

@end
```

And the implementation file `ActivityImage+MyStuff.m`:

```
#import "ActivityImage+MyStuff.h"

@implementation ActivityImage

+ (void)getActivityImage:(NSUInteger)someInteger
{
    // Whatever it does
}

@end
```

and finally in the code you want to use the category in:

```
#import "ActivityImage+MyStuff.h"

[ActivityImage getActivityImage:2];
```

Comment: Yep, it is a category file! And, throughout my project I use it as such. But, I guess my question is how I can use a category made in my project, inside a framework that I added?

Comment: @BrianW You have to move the category into whatever code you want to use it from.  I wish you had mentioned that you were already using categories as it would have saved me lots of time and typing :-/

Comment: I apologize :( I saw all that and was hoping you hadn't just typed all of that (was hoping it was just a copy from Apples site or something). I appreciate that you were willing to write all that out. In any case, it seems like I have to customize the category... which I'm not sure is doable.